# Python - Obtaining value from a boolean function without accessing it

Tags: python-3.x

When needing the output of a function such as:

```
def _hasWon(self):
   if self == True
      return True
   else 
      return False
```

Then later setting this via:

```
self._hasWon(True)
```

But if I need to check `if _hasWon is True` later, how would I check it without calling the function?
I currently have:

```
if self._hasWon(self)
```

This calls the function again, however, which will change the existing value.  How should this be rewritten?

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing something wrong here.

If you are using a class, you could something like

```
Class MyClass:
    def hasWon(self, won):
        self.won = won # won is bool
```

Now set the value like this

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.hasWon(True)
```

And get the value as

`obj.hasWon`

Comment: Thank you, this setup is more logical than what I was doing.

Comment: Glad this helped. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to keep the state in the function, but using a class seems to be more common solution

```
def _hasWon(self, previous=[]):
    if not previous:
        previous.append(self)
    return next(iter(previous))
```

It will return the first value got passed until you pass an empty list as a second argument to set a new state